# what should i do to resolve this warning

Tags: c

the program warning a bug that

```
main.c:38:7: error: conflicting types for 'remove'; have 'Node *(int,  Node *)'
   38 | Node* remove(int v, Node* h){
      |       ^~~~~~
In file included from main.c:2:
/usr/include/stdio.h:152:12: note: previous declaration of 'remove' with type 'int(const char *)'
  152 | extern int remove (const char *__filename) __THROW;
      |            ^~~~~~
Compile Error
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int value;
    struct Node*next;
}Node;

Node*first;

Node*makeNode(int v){
    Node*p=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->value=v; p->next=NULL;
    return p;
}

void printList(Node* h){
    Node* p=h;
    while(p != NULL){
        printf("%d ", p->value);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

Node* addlast(int k, Node* h){
    Node* q= makeNode(k);
    if(h==NULL) return q;
    Node* p= h;
    while (p->next != NULL){
        p= p->next;
    }
    p -> next = q;
    return h;
}

Node* remove(int v, Node* h){
    Node* q= makeNode(v);
    if(h==NULL) return h;
    Node* p=h;
    if(p->value==v){
        Node* tmp=p;
        p->next=tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
        return p;
    }
    while (p->next != NULL){
        if (p->next->value ==v){
            Node* tmp=p->next;
            p->next=tmp->next;
            free(tmp);
            return h;
        }
        p= p->next;
    }
}

Node* addafter(int v, int u, Node* h){
    Node* q= makeNode(v);
    if(h==NULL) return h;
    else{
    Node* p= h;
    while (p->value != u){
        p= p->next;
    }
    Node* tmp=p->next;
    p -> next = q;
    q->next= tmp;
    return h;
}
}

Node* addbefor(int v, int u, Node* h){
    Node* q= makeNode(v);
    if(h==NULL) return h;
    else{
    Node* p= h;
    while (p->next->value != u){
        p= p->next;
    }
    Node* tmp=p->next;
    p -> next = q;
    q->next= tmp;
    return h;
}
}

Node* addfirst(int k, Node* first){
    Node* q= makeNode(k);
    Node* h= first;
    Node* tmp=q;
    first=q;
    q->next=h;  
        return first;
}

Node* reverse(Node* first){
    
}

int check(int v){
    Node* h=first;
    while (h->value != v || h==NULL){
        h=h->next;
    }
    if (h->value==v) return 0;
    if (h==NULL) return 1;
}

int main() {
    first = NULL;
    int n, v, x, y, z;
    char a[10];
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &v);
        first=addlast(v,first);
    }
    do{
        scanf("%s", &a);
        
            if (strcmp(a, "addlast")==0){
                scanf ("%d", &x);
                if(check(x))
                first=addlast(x, first);
            }
            if (strcmp(a, "addfirst")==0){
                scanf ("%d", &x);
                if(check(x))
                first=addfirst(x, first);
            }
            if (strcmp(a, "remove")==0){
                scanf ("%d", &x);
                first=remove(x, first);
            }
            if (strcmp(a, "addafter")==0){
                scanf ("%d%d", &x, &y);
                if(check(y))
                first=addafter(y, x, first);
            }
            if (strcmp(a, "addbefor")==0){
                scanf ("%d%d", &x, &y);
                if(check(y))
                first=addbefor(y, x, first);
            }
            
    } while (strcmp(a, "#")!=0);
    printList(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag `C++` when this is `C`?  If this is supposed to be C++, you are not learning it properly, since usage of `malloc` and `free` is not advised, `typedef struct` is redundant, and this entire code is `std::list<int>` or `std::forward_list<int>`

Comment: Why is your [mre] so long? The error message mentions `main.c`, `remove`, and `stdio.h`, so a good stab at reducing the example code would be the minimal amount needed to pull in these elements: `#include<stdio.h> typedef struct Node{ int value; } Node; Node* remove(int v, Node* h){ return NULL; }`

Comment: I recommend reading [ask]. Your question's title says very little about the subject of your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. This is my first time i write a ques so i have some mistake. In the next time i will improve my writing question skill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove) is a function in the C standard library, found in [`<stdio.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io), with the signature:

```
int remove(const char *pathname);
```

You will need to name your

```
Node *remove(int v, Node *h);
```

function something else to avoid conflicting with it, e.g.:

```
Node *my_remove(int v, Node *h);
```